# Building First Large React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

New React developer here. I'm planning on starting my first major project for my business. I have a ton of Excel templates for various purposes (prioritization, standard operating procedures, problem solving, root cause analysis, etc.). My idea is to put everything online and build out a system my customers can use for their facilities. Each facility would have a manager, then various users under them. Security is obviously important.

Most tutorials merely show a single page application, but this is far larger. What is the proper way to build something like this out from a technology standpoint? High level overview is fine....looking for guidance.

Best way to handle routes?

Do I use Express in some way shape or form since it can do rendering on the back-end?

How do I connect Express/React if I use this combination? I've read about client/server, but haven't found anything conclusive online that's more recent.

Many thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, this seems like a bit larger of a subject than can be handled adequately in this site format.  You appear to be asking for design suggestions/recommendations, which are very subjective and could create multiple equally correct answers, which is against the way this site functions.

Comment: You appear to be asking on advice about how to build an app for your company, my advice is, go hire a designer and some developers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this question would need to be heavily revised to be a good fit for the website. It currently includes multiple questions in one, seeks recommendations for software libraries, and is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. If you can narrow your question down to one particular aspect of the project design you need answered, in a way that is not seeking recommendations for software libraries, and invites only objective fact-based answers, then your question can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to React/Web Development, but for my projects I like to use a framework on top of React to make scaling easier. My favorites are [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.com) and [NextJS](https://nextjs.org).

They are both 'static site generators,' in that the end result is static html/css/minimal javascript which loads really quickly. However, NextJS is cool because it's kind of in between a frontend and backend, in that you can use dynamic rendering or server api calls all within its framework so it can do more than just generate a static website. For what you're talking about, I think NextJS could be a good idea.

You can definitely connect a React frontend to an Express backend, [here's a youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJA9rDX7azM). In my opinion as a somewhat novice web developer, using frameworks like Gatsby or NextJS are way easier. I like that with those frameworks you can just create a file in the /pages/ directory of your src files and it will automatically become a page of your website, and with Next (and maybe Gatbsy too) you can make dynamic routes so you can programmatically create pages.

EDIT: Like the comment to your post says, this answer is very subjective! Hopefully it gives you thinks to look into, though.

Comment: This is exactly the advice I was looking for. Thank you!